# Refactor-renaming of class causes termination

Tags: ios, xcode, rename

I renamed a class with the refactor function, but now the app crashes with an error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason:   '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class
```

When i keep the old name everything works fine. So i assume XCode did not change all of the old names so now there is an unchanged piece of code somewhere in my project, that causes the termination, but i cannot find it! I looked especially around the NSKeyedUnarchiever function where the error according to xcode appeared, but i am not able to locate it.

So do you guys have ideas what might be the problem? Or is it just so that i have to look more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you loading your own archive? Or the class name is in an XIB / storyboard?

Comment: Yes my own, it is just a normal class with just 2 properties, so nothing special!

Comment: So you created an archive and then changed the name of the class that is archived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have changed the name of a class in an archive you need to teach the unarchiver how to deal with that (it isn't magic). Use `setClass:forClassName:` to set the new class for the old class name.